# Validation Expression accepting ENTER too

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, email-validation

am having a bad luck in validation of multiple emails seprated with comma Or Semi colon.

```
ValidationExpression="(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*([;: ]+)?)+"
```

This validation works fine when multiple email separated with comma OR colon, but what i need more to bypass ENTER input too. Means if user hits enter after writing each emails.
How can i modify above expression so that it can eat Enter as well as comma and semi colon,

Thanks in advance

Using this in asp.net .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see how that works with commas but this should make it work with multiple lines.

```
(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*([;:\s]+)?)+
```

If you want it to work for commas I would think it would need to be this:

```
(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*([,;:\s]+)?)+
```

I should point out that I did not do anything to validate whether or not that was actually a good regex for validating email addresses. I just added the requested functionality.

I highly recommend [The Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/) to help you build regex.

I also highly recommend http://www.regular-expressions.info/ as a reference.